# How would we go on to create a Hexagonal menu system using CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm thinking of a menu system, pretty much resembling a beehive, where you click the main hexagon and it will fade in 6 new hexagons around it, all being menu items. I have tried to create this, the first part worked, but I'm trying to make it reusable, reusable as in we can determine which elements get the beehive menu, even the ones inside the already created menu should be able to get the beehive effect. What would be the measures needed to create this reusable menu system? or is it still out of my skill level to do something like this?

You can check out the code here [github repo](https://github.com/alalfakawma/beehive-test). I just could not make it work in a reusable fashion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Once I tried to do something like that. The best way to start is using a graphic library, like [d3](https://d3js.org/).

A few examples:

- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5249328
- http://bl.ocks.org/ericsoco/cb80d8205e5277a3f8f0b0e26781d2b5
- http://sunsp.net/demo/BubbleMenu/ (in this one, you need to change the shape to hexagon)

D3 uses SVG to do that. If you don't want to use an API, you can build your own implementation (I don't recommend that), by using SVG, because is the simplest way to do that (you can create the svg in the js instead of another file, and add events for example)

Comment: I'm using js to add the svg's into the markup, otherwise it get's real messy. I like the way the example's are there. But the main problem is always the reusability of the code, I pretty much want a hex menu to stack just as a normal li menu would, but it's kind of hard to achieve that without hardcoding it for now. I will defo check d3 out. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: >But the main problem is always the reusability of the code. If you make a good JS function you dont even need to make anything in the html (normal li menu)

Comment: I just created something, that is fully reusable. Check it out, and share if possible, still refining it. https://github.com/alalfakawma/easyHex